# Como ocupar el 100% de la altura de la pagina

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

estoy intentando hacer un navbar pero tengo problema en el responsive al intentar ocupar el 100% del alto de la pantalla, alguna solución?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Navbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />

    <!-- FONT AWESOME -->
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/96fadf0e69.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <!-- FONT AWESOME -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <img class="navbar__logo" src="gamezonia.png" alt="logo" />

      <ul class="navbar__list">
        <li class="list__item">Inicio</li>
        <li class="list__item">Categoria 1</li>
        <li class="list__item">Categoria 2</li>
        <li class="list__item">Categoria 3</li>
        <li class="list__item">Contacto</li>
        <li class="list__item">Acceder</li>
        <li class="list__item--search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="navbar__hamburger">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>prueba</li>
    </ul>

    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.navbar{
    display: flex;
    background-color: #2B2F33;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}


.navbar__logo{
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
    width: 25%;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.navbar__list{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    align-items: center;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.list__item{
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.list__item--search{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.navbar__hamburger{
    display: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    align-self: center;
}

@media (max-width: 850px){

    .navbar{
        position: relative;
    }

    .navbar__list{
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 30%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: #2B2F33;
        top: 100%;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s;
    }

    .navbar__hamburger{
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: 30px;
    }

    .showMenu{
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }

    .list__item, .list__item--search{
        padding: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    
}
```

JS:

```
console.log('works')

document.querySelector('.navbar__hamburger').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    document.querySelector('.navbar__list').classList.toggle('showMenu')
})
```

Comment: Usa `height: 100vh;` en el elemento que quiere que ocupe todo el height. En tu caso creo que es el `.navbar`

Comment: Ya lo tiene .navbar__list en la media query

Comment: Correcto pero no el `.navbar` intenta a ver. lo otro es que la semantica the tu unordered list no esta bien, estas creando un nuevo par `ul li` por cada item, se que es una prueba pero igual no es correcto como lo has montado.

Comment: Si lo pongo en el .navbar se modifica todo el navbar, yo solo quiero la lista ocupe todo el ancho de la pantalla, y los de los ul li los puse así a propósito, para crear el scroll

Comment: Creo que estas tratando de resolver algo que no esta bien ejecutado. Te recomiendo usar un `div` que acoja el `nav` y un solo `ul` a este `div` le das un attributo de `display: flex` o `grid` y se te hara mas facil controlar el flujo del DOM

Comment: Con lo del div se arreglo, gracias

Comment: Me alegro que lo lograster resolver!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usar: `height: 100 vh;` te da el completo de el monitor o pantalla que se esté usando para ver esa página... si quieres que ocupe toda la página, no solo el completo de la pantalla usa: `height: 100%;`